# How do I download/open a pdf file directly by clicking on lable/link

Tags: 7, views, files

I have created a view that displays in a bulletin format, which works fine. My challenge is when I click on the bulletin which has a pdf attachment, I want it to immediately download/open the attached pdf file. Currently it takes me to  second screen(see attached) which has a pdf attachment. I would like to get pdf attachment downloaded immediately when I click on the bulletin, **National Arts Festival Grahamstown 27 June to 7 July 2013** from the first screen(see attached).

I have tried to use file force drupal module but seems not to be doing the trick.

Herewith an attachments.
[image: first screen]
[image: second screen]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If want to Download File, then use [DownloadFile](http://drupal.org/project/download_file) module.

> a module to direct download files or images.

If want to open PDF, then use [PDF Reader](http://drupal.org/project/pdf_reader) module

> will render your entity file fields with the selected PDF renderer.

and [PDF](http://drupal.org/project/pdf) module.

> Use HTML5 to display PDF files if users don't have pdf plugin for
>   their browsers.